# Refresh activity if preferences was changed

Tags: android, android-activity, settings, refresh, preferences

I have a PreferenceActivity with settings for my app and I want to refresh activity if some preferences was changed.

For example I have a checkbox which responsible for addtional tab in my layout, when checkbox is checked tab must be shown. To catch this event I used OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener. But this listener listen every click on this checkbox and do something (your logic) every time, every click even though setting really was not changed. I want to refresh my activity only if setting was really changed. If earlier was "OFF" and now become "ON" in this case I want to refresh, but if I changed OFF - ON  - OFF I don't want to refresh.

How to catch really changes and how to handle this in activity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to catch really changes and how to handle this in activity?

Step #1: Implement the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` on your main activity.

Step #2: Maintain a `boolean` data member, initially `false`, which you toggle whenever your checkbox of interest is changed.

Step #3: In `onStart()` or `onResume()`, if the `boolean` data member is `true`, refresh the activity and set the data member to `false`.